# FLTK: Override the FL_box constructor. C++

Tags: c++, c, qt, user-interface, fltk

I'm trying to make a window using FLTK (fast light took kit). I get this error while compiling. Could anybody help please!

My code in fltk1.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Box.H>

//Drawing functions
#include <FL/fl_draw.H>

// Subclass of Fl_box
class dotbox : public Fl_Box {  
int x = 180;
public:

using Fl_Box::Fl_Box; //Inherits the constructor from base (C++11)

  void draw() override{ //Override draw from box ('override' er C++11)   


    fl_color(FL_RED); 
    fl_pie(160,80,30,30,0,360); //draw

    fl_color(FL_GREEN); //...repeats
    fl_pie(170,90,40,40,0,360);

    fl_color(FL_BLUE);
    fl_pie(x++,100,30,30,0,360);
  }
};
```

The Error: Which I get while compiling:

```
    Building for 1.3.3
g++ -std=c++11 fltk1.cpp -o fltk1 -L/usr/local/lib -lfltk -lXfixes -lXext -lpthread -ldl -lm -lX11
fltk1.cpp:15:15: error: ‘Fl_Box::Fl_Box’ names constructor
fltk1.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
fltk1.cpp:50:37: error: no matching function for call to ‘dotbox::dotbox(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
fltk1.cpp:50:37: note: candidates are:
fltk1.cpp:11:7: note: dotbox::dotbox() <deleted>
fltk1.cpp:11:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 4 provided
fltk1.cpp:11:7: note: dotbox::dotbox(const dotbox&) <deleted>
fltk1.cpp:11:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 4 provided
fltk1.cpp:51:41: error: no matching function for call to ‘dotbox::dotbox(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
fltk1.cpp:51:41: note: candidates are:
fltk1.cpp:11:7: note: dotbox::dotbox() <deleted>
fltk1.cpp:11:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 4 provided
fltk1.cpp:11:7: note: dotbox::dotbox(const dotbox&) <deleted>
fltk1.cpp:11:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 4 provided
make: *** [fltk] Error 1
```

Any idea?

I fixed this issue by uncommenting,

//using FL_Box::Fl_Box; 
and adding this line of code instead.

```
   dotbox(int X, int Y, int W, int H) : Fl_Box(X, Y, W, H, 0) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by uncommenting,

`//using FL_Box::Fl_Box;` and adding this line of code instead.

```
 dotbox(int X, int Y, int W, int H) : Fl_Box(X, Y, W, H, 0) {}
```